# Adding paramters to VSTS Task Group

Tags: azure-devops

I have a Task Group that I created out of a set of build tasks. I am able to edit the tasks quite well, but i now realise i will need to add another parameter to the task group. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Task group parameters are automatically created based on the variables used in the tasks. If you reference a new variable in a task that's within a task group, it will pop up.

Comment: Thank you. I also found that out myself.

Comment: It will pop up if it is written in a required field. If your for instance type a variable name in the Display Name of a task, then it will not appear when you save the task group changes.

Comment: Under some circumstances the variables are not automatically propagated to the taskGroup face.
As a workaround I added an extra step - inline PowerShell script where i simply use the so far not-presented variables. After that --> save your task group. The variables become visible :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the accepted answer, if you want to add parameters that are not directly referenced by tasks within the tasks group (e.g. to use in a config file token replacement task) then you can export your task group, edit the .json file then import it back in. The parameters are in an inputs array near the end of file. You can also hide parameters here if you only want to use them internally to the task group by setting a default value and adding a 'visibleRule' property, see this article for details: https://medium.com/objectsharp/how-to-hide-a-task-group-parameter-b95f7c85870c

This will create a new task group rather than updating your current task group. If you want to update the task group, you can use this REST API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/taskgroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: if we edit something in the Task group, won't this get re-evaluated and be removed (and so require the export/edit/import cycle again?